# Find and prove a formula for $1\pmod{3}\cap 1\pmod{7}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

> Find and prove a formula for $1\pmod{3}\cap 1\pmod{7}$.

I have tried looking at similar problems where $A$ is a subset of $B$ iff $A \cap B =A$. But it does not seem to work.

What type of formula should I be looking for and proving?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you want $x$ such that $x\equiv1\bmod 3$ and $7$? That's the (constant case of the) [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem)

Comment: But $A$ ***is*** a subset of $B$ iff $A \cap B = A$.

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathrm{lcm}(3,7)=21$.

Comment: ??? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3598094/find-and-prove-a-formula-for-1-3-cap-1-7

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "$1 \mod 3 \cap 1 \mod 7$" means the set of all integers that are congruent to 1 mod both 3 and 7, then the answer is the set of all integers that are congruent to 1 mod 21. This is because $n-1$ is divisible by 21 if and only if it is divisible by both 3 and 7, so the statements "$n \equiv 1 \pmod{21}$" and "$(n \equiv 1 \pmod{3}) \land (n \equiv 1 \pmod{7})$" are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

$$[a]_n:=\{ b\in\Bbb Z: n\mid a-b\},$$

we have

$$\begin{align}
x\in[1]_3\cap[1]_7&\Leftrightarrow x\in[1]_3 \land x\in[1]_7 \\
&\Leftrightarrow 3\mid (1-x) \land 7\mid (1-x) \\
&\Leftrightarrow 21\mid (1-x)\\
&\Leftrightarrow x\in[1]_{21}.
\end{align}$$

Hence $[1]_3\cap[1]_7=[1]_{21}.$